# no template named 'tuple' in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, stdtuple

I am not allowed to initialise a tuple in C++. When I compile it comes up the following error while pointen at `tuple`: `no template named 'tuple'`. I am using Mac and have specified my `tasks.json` as shown in the bottom of the page.

**Code**

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    tuple<int,int> f;

    return 0;
}
```

**Error message:**

```
error: no template named 'tuple'
tuple<int,int> f;
^
```

1 error generated.

**tasks.json** (taken from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac where I have followed their guidelines):

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
            "-std=c++17",
            "-stdlib=libc++",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build"
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
]
```

}

**Compiler**

```
% clang --version
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: My guess is that the task `cppbuild` is used and not the `shell` one, and that the default c++ version there does not support `tuple`. So add `"-std=c++17",` also to the `args` of `cppbuild` and check if it works then.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, though I have mentioned `-std=c++17` in the `args` of `cppbuild`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, the problem was, that the task `cppbuild` was used instead of `shell`, and for that task, no c++ version was defined. Due to that default version for that compiler was used which does not support `tuple`.

Adding `"-std=c++17",` to the `args` of `cppbuild` solves that problem.